# How to send the value from javascript part of code to the ascx.cs code file

Tags: c#, javascript, ascx

In my .ascx page there was some javascript functions.I want to send the value from this java script function to the codebehind file to execute a method.

I tried to use PageMethods but it was getting errors.As i google about this problem i found that PageMethods cannot use with .ascx control pages it can be only used with .aspx pages.

Please give me some suggestion how could i perform my task..

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way seems to be is to refactor the functionality you want to run into an aspx page (as you can use pagemethods) and call it using javascript.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,Actually i need to store the search values from URL into database.I am thinking that i will store this from javascript as a cookie and then retrieve the cookie from c# code and save it as a string in database.Do u thik it works

Comment: @Subha if you are just storing search values from URL then will not it be better to **extract** them from **query string** and push to db when you search, rather than going all the trouble of using cookies?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a webservice instead of pagemethods. Check out the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398998.aspx) doc  it has a pretty decent example.